# How to hide passed view controllers (By segue) in iOS

Tags: ios, segue, viewcontroller

I have 3 view controllers: A, B & C
when A calls B, in viewWillAppear method of B, I call C
Now I want to change it, so that users don't feel the transitions participated by B.
Could anyone help?

Comment: may be viewWillAppear animation:NO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the storyboard-> select the segue witch connect A and B -> go the attribute inspector -> uncheck "animates" checkBox.

keep your code in viewWillApear.

let me know if this helps you :)

Comment: I have a similar requirement where I "optionally" want to animate the seque or not. However the Segue Animate property does not appear accessible programatically?